# jqGrid typeerror jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm getting really strange error with jqGrid regarding a TypeError. I've used the grid on many other sites but for whatever reason can't it to work on my latest one.

I put in the loadError handler and I get "TypeError: a is null" and Firebug tells me the error is in jquery itself. I've multiple version of both the grid and jQuery -- same result. I made sure my code matched what was on the demoes. Still nothing. Firebug shows the json request went through.

Here's my JSON (it's one row for now):

```
{"total":6960,"page":1,"records":6960,"rows":[{"id":1000000477,"cell":["some title","brain","7\/15\/2010 at 8:33 AM","sometest",5,277]}]}
```

Here's my grid set up:

```
$('#threads').jqGrid({
url: '/pxr/getthreads',
dataType: 'json',
colNames:['Thread / Started By','Last Post','Replies','Views'], 
colModel:[{name:'title',index:'title',width:330,sortable:false},
          {name:'lastpost',index:'lastpost', width:130,sortable:false}, 
          {name:'replies',index:'replycount', width:60, align:"left",sortable:false}, 
          {name:'views',index:'views', width:60, align:"center",sortable:false}],
rowNum:1,
autowidth:true,
pager: $('div#threadsPager'),
hidegrid:false,
scrollOffset:0,
height: 600, 
altRows:false,    
sortname: 'lastpost',
viewrecords: true,
emptyrecords: "No Threads Found",
sortorder: 'asc', 
pginput:true,
loadError: function(xhr,status,error){
    console.log(error);
},
caption:"" });
```

I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 and jqGrid 3.8. My server page renders valid json.

html:

```
<table id="threads"></table><div id="threadsPager"></div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in your code very easy, but can be difficult be seen: you should change `dataType: 'json'` to `datatype: 'json'`. After the change the data can be loaded: see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HapiDjus.htm).

Comment: I knew it was something that plain as day... very "duh!" moment. :-) Good catch.

Comment: @HapiDjus: Congratulation! One more important tip. Starting with 15 points of reputations you have right to vote up any question or any good answer on the stackoverflow.com. There are one common simple rule which you can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask): "As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer." The voting system helps to find the best questions and answers on the stackoverflow.com. You have the right to vote and I recommend to use it. Best wishes from me!